# Listing files from the network in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jruby, jrubyonrails

I'd like to be able to list files from a distant directory on the network with Rails (for instance, listing every pictures in a folder to move them and do some processing on them).

So I tried to first list them by doing :

```
<% @files = Dir.glob("\\my\directory\on\the network\*" ) %>
<% @files.each do |file| %>
    <%= file %>
<% end %>
```

But I have no output, nothing, not even an error message or something.
If anyone have a clue...

Thanks !

Comment: Is using the SMB (windows shares) protocol the only way of accessing the remote directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
<%- @files = Dir.entries("//my/directory/on/the/network") %>
<%- @files.each do |file| %>
    <%= file %>
<% end %>
```